# Adress Book Sharing between Mac OSX and Windows on Google drive

Tags: networking

I'm working with an Apple MacBookPro (OS X 10.6.8) and have my business contacts in the tool Address Book.app.

I want to share my address book with my business partner who is working with a windows system.

So, I've placed my address book on google drive and sent an access to my business partner. Unfortunately he is not able to open the address book.

Question:
It seems, that my colleague should also install the Address Book app. Does this app exists for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Select all your contacts and `drag` them to your shared folder. It'll export them in `vCard` format. If you're lucky than your partner will recognize that format :)

Or you may use `ab2csv` utility from [antoniolore.net](http://www.antoniolore.net/), to export it to universal CSV sheet.

Comment: Hello Dave,

Thanks a lot for your answer - I appreciate your efforts very much!

With my best regards and have a nice evening,
Carina